# How to skip an index Java?

Tags: java, string

I need help with skipping a specific index in an array. Say I divided them with `String.split()` and I wanted everything to print out except for the first string, how would I accomplish this? I've been trying to find for an answer for an hour and haven't found anything, please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
  public static Scanner Link = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String Zelda = Link.nextLine();
      String[] str = Zelda.split("\\s");
      System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to print the string minus the specific index, you could: (1) declare a stringbuilder (2) iterate through str array via for loop, calling your stringbuilder.append( str[i] ) when i != 0 (or i != whatever index you want to skip), then (3) print the stringbuilder.toString()

Answer (score 1):

> i wanted everything to print out except for the first string

```
int first = 0;
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
   if(i!=first)//except for the first string   
   System.out.println(str[i]);
}
```

OR

```
Arrays.asList(str).subList(index, str.length);
```

[List#subList() doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

the followong code can print what you want... you can skip any index of your choice as long as it exists in between 0 and your string array's length-1.

```
String Zelda = "akash:kumar:coder"; // test string
String[] str = Zelda.split(":");
for(int i = 0; i<str.length; i++)
   {
    if(i==1) //Index you want to skip
    {
      continue;
    }
    System.out.println(str[i]);
  }
```

For more on continue statement... see this... [Branching Statements in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)) to get sub array:

```
 str = Arrays.copyOfRange (str, 1, str.length);
 System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] str = Zelda.split("\\s",-1);
System.out.println(Arrays.copyOfRange(str, 1, str.length);
```

Notice that Arrays.copyOfRange requires jdk 1.6 or higher. If you use java 5 you could use System.arrayCopy instead.